# RSSI Calculation in ns2

Tags: geolocation, ns2, rssi

I need to know the RSSI value of non anchor nodes when anchor nodes transmit signal when a simulation is run using Two ray Ground Model. I need to use those values to estimate non anchor node location.

I am a NS2 beginner. Some detailed steps would help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the value of Pr, which can be found in the packet object

```
p->txinfo_.getTxPr();
```

and

```
p->txinfo_.RxPr
```

where p is the received packet
TxPr is the power with which packet is transmitted 
RxPr is the power with which packet is received